# Photo distorted in Html Need Help Rendering too 500x375

Tags: html

My photo in my html is not rendering long enough. I would like the photo to look less distorted but i am pretty new to html. The original photo is 500x375. I was hoping to make it render in my html block with those exact dimensions.

Comment: It should render at its native dimensions unless you've explicitly set its size elsewhere, or the size of its container. If you could include your code it would help.

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: Robbie, please check my answer. Is that the answer you were looking for? If it's not, you can leave a comment asking for more help. If it was though, you can mark it as accepted, which shows others that this question has been answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the `height` and `width` attributes on your `img` tag:

```
<img src="myfile.jpg" width="500" height="375"/>
```

That will set its dimensions to 500x375 pixels. Your image should already have these styles automatically though, so it's likely that your image's styles are being modified by a stylesheet. To counteract this, you can also define an inline style to override those other styles:

```
<img src="myfile.jpg" style="width:500px;height:375"/>
```

This will override other styles that are applied to the image.